# Why do the elements of arrays have to be defined inside a method?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new, still have a lot of learning to do, and this is probably a very basic level question.  But I don't understand why I have to add `int`s to the elements of the array from the inside of a method.

I can't just have

```
public class staticvars {

int[] Grokk = new int[5];

Grokk[0] = 12
}
```

Maybe this bad design for some reason, but I planned on having a class file with many of my static variables that I want to load when my program starts, and just initialize all my variables when my program starts through that class file.

Comment: Well.. The reason you can't do that is because the language wasn't designed to allow that. You might be able to use a static initializer block to solve your problem. (If I understood your problem correctly)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but why not  do something like: int[] grokk=new int[]{12,13,14,15};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not allow statements in "the middle of nowhere" - all statements should be done in methods, constructors or static initializers. The one exception to this rule is member initializations, which are just a syntactic sugar over placing this code in a constructor.

In your case, unless you use an inline initialization to initialize the entire `Grokk` array ...

```
int[] Grokk = new int[] {12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
```

... You'd have to put this code in a constructor:

```
public class staticvars {

    int[] Grokk = new int[5];

    public staticvars() {
        Grokk[0] = 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the inline initialization possibility.